# Communicate with an https server(SAP j2ee server) uising Ajax, jQuery and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, blackberry

I am very new to the phonegap platform, and i am on research about the issue below for the last two weeks.
I am working on a PhoneGap project for android which communicates with a remote https server(SAP j2ee server). I dont have any controll over server. The server gives data as SOAP response only in a secured way.

Now my problem is that i am not able to send a request from my application to the server. When i send a request i get either HTTP Status 'error' or a success message without any data.

Is there any alternative methods available for the same issue for android and blackberry?

Please go through the code below and please help me.

```
function soapRequest(){
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    var username=$("#username").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();


    var SOAP_Login='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:OrSVi"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><urn:getP><urn:userName>'+username+'</urn:userName></urn:getP></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';
    $.ajax({
            url: URL_Login,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            async:false,
            cache: false,
            crossDomain:true,
            data: SOAP_Login,
            complete: endSaveProduct,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPTarget", "https://ex.example.com:443/OrSvi/Config1?style=document");
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic WFWeMjEyMDerebWrteTyyku=="); 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","urn:OrSviWsd/OrSVi_Document/getPRequest");
            },
            contentType: "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
        });
}
```